# identity server 4 unable to get email when authenticating with office 365

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I am using identityserver4 and authenticating with office 365.  I can see email in the token I receive from office 365 unfortunately the email never shows up back on the mvc client when I query the user object.

I can see the email in identityserver4  in the startup.cs in

```
   options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = ctx =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Claims from the ID token");
                foreach (var claim in ctx.Principal.Claims)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{claim.Type} - {claim.Value}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Claims from the UserInfo endpoint");
                foreach (var property in ctx.User.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name} - {property.Value}");
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

unfortunately on the razor page of the client mvc the email claim does not exist.

  @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => claim.Type)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => claim.Value)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

> ```
> Claim Type    Claim Value
> s_hash    OpiGCfrQ9Cc71rXb3iFC0Q
> sid   000180029368B13BA99045D16BF07156
> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier  7D6B74E7E17AFE5640B41EC0EC8E003E2B3C22117DE82D64EFA6B935EF3DD93E
> auth_time 1682352357
> http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider AzureAD
> http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences    external
> ```

here is my openid connect in identityserver startup.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("AzureAD", "Office 365", options =>
    {
        options.ClaimActions.MapAllExcept("iss", "nbf", "exp", "aud", "nonce", "iat", "c_hash");
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("preferred_username", "preferred_username");
        options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("email", "email");
        options.ClientId = "edf44846-5e26-409e-b4de-59676a88e0c3";
        options.ClientSecret = "FJd8Q~-wGZfozfIfPdb9z5W_i1fGy4xZLBNMXdjW"; // Add your client secret here
        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/44f5f615-327a-4d5a-86d5-c9251297d7e4/v2.0";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");

        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";

        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = ctx =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Claims from the ID token");
            foreach (var claim in ctx.Principal.Claims)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{claim.Type} - {claim.Value}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Claims from the UserInfo endpoint");
            foreach (var property in ctx.User.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name} - {property.Value}");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };


    });
```

I have the email scope in my identityserver config.cs

```
      AllowedScopes = new List<string>
        {
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
            "movieAPI",
        },
        Enabled = true // Make sure the client is enabled
    }
                };
            public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
               new ApiScope[]
               {
                   new ApiScope("movieAPI", "Movie API")
               };
            public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
             new ApiResource[]
            {
    
            };
            public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new IdentityResource[]
           {
               new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
               new IdentityResources.Profile(),
               new IdentityResources.Email(),
           };

and I have the scope added to the AddOpenIdConnect in the starup.cs of the MVC client

.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5005"; // IdentityServer4 endpoint
    options.ClientId = "edf44846-5e26-409e-b4de-59676a88e0c3"; // Client ID from IdentityServer4 configuration
    options.ResponseType = "id_token token"; // Use "id_token token" for the implicit flow

    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("movieAPI");

    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.GivenName,
    };
});
```

Comment: I did a blog post about debugging OpenIDConnect problems here https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: @Tore Nestenius yes thanks I actually had read through that before I posted thanks for that.  what I finally had to do which is shameful but only way I could do it was get the email on the options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived get the email `ctx.User.RootElement.GetString("email");`  then store it in a static dictionary and then made a customprofileservice where I retrieved it and added it as a claim

Comment: one quick thought, I think its bad to use  MapUniqueJsonKey and MapAllExcept at the same time. :-)